# bgiframe does not work on FireFox

Tags: jquery, bgiframe

I have a problem when display a jquery dialog over an applet image viewer (or ActiveX image viewer) (the size of applet larger than jquery dialog)

```
$("#dialogDiv").dialog({
                ...
                ,bgiframe:true
                });
```

In IE, it work fine (didn't tested on IE 6),but not work on FireFox
So, i'm tricked by disable the bgiframe option in $ dialog and manually create an iframe by

```
 $("#dialogDiv").bgiframe({ top: 0, left: 0, width: 400, height: 200 })
```

The iframe is created successfully in IE8, but not in FireFox (v3.6.12).

I used this script:  jquery.bgiframe.min.js

Please help me to find out the root cause.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I've never had to use this plugin, but looking at their documentation it says it only applies to IE6.

http://brandonaaron.net/code/bgiframe/docs/

Can you explain a little better what are you trying to achieve? Maybe you don't need bgiframe

Comment: hi Ives, When display a jQuery dialog over an <applet> tag, i'm set bgiframe option = true --> it work fine on IE, but in FireFox, it same didn't generate the iframe element, so the jquery dialog still display behide the <applet>

Comment: I understand now. I used to have a similar problem when using a Xstandard (http://www.xstandard.com/). The only solution I've found was to hide it when displaying the dialog. Usually the dialog has callbacks before opening and after closing.

Comment: Example of dialog doing callback http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html

Comment: hi Ives,I have updated on my question for more detail.My expectation is show up the dialog on the top of order (of applet, activeX image viewer).In your example , i see you created an div element with display:none styling as the background model for dialog, but in my situation, the background is the applet.

Comment: Hey again, there is a thread here http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-ui/browse_thread/thread/5accf5728a3269be and they suggested to make changes to the z-index.

Comment: I tried on that approach, it only work for IE, anyway, i trying work around with some adjustment on you link, and will feedback to you soon.

Comment: Hi Ives, TrietNguyen have a comment for you.